# MongoDB Aggregate by Multiple Fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have a dataset that I want to aggregate by several fields and I'm having a hard time coming up with a single pipeline. The dataset looks as follows:

```
[
  {
    "filename": "file1.js",
    "editor": "vscode",
    "lines": 45,
    // Just for illustration.
    // It's a real datetime in Mongo.
    "date": "2019-02-21"
  },
  {
    "filename": "file1.js",
    "editor": "vscode",
    "lines": 32,
    "date": "2019-02-21"
  },
  {
    "filename": "file2.js",
    "editor": "vim",
    "lines": 57,
    "date": "2019-02-22"
  },
  {
    "filename": "file2.js",
    "editor": "vim",
    "lines": 18,
    "date": "2019-02-22"
  }
]
```

Based on the date, filename, and editor, I want to provide statistics for each of those fields. I want to group by date first, than sum up the number of lines for each file and editor. Right now, I have this group aggregate that groups by date and filename:

```
{
  _id: {
      date: {
      day: { $dayOfMonth: "$date" },
      month: { $month: "$date" },
      year: { $year: "$date"}
    },
    filename: '$filename'
  },
  lines: { $sum: '$lines' }
}
```

I'd have to run the same exact aggregate also for the editors (and other fields I have omitted from the sample), and considering there are quite a lot of data (tens of thousands), not sure if that's the most performant option. What I want to achieve is a single aggregate the produces a result similar to the following. Numbers are totally made up, just to give the idea.

```
{
   dates: {
     "2019-02-22": {
        // total lines for each file
        files: [
          { name: 'file1.js', lines: 100 }
        ],
        // total lines for each editor
        editors: [
          { name: 'vscode', lines: 87 }
        ],
        totals: { lines: 170 } // total lines for the day
      },
      "2019-02-21": {
        files: [
          { name: 'file2.js', lines: 100 }
        ],
        editors: [
          { name: 'vim', lines: 140 }
        ],
        totals: { lines: 220 }
      }
   },
   totals: { lines: 390 } // total lines for the days combines
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $facet https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

I have just created one basic sample for your example which can be extended by adding facets pipeline stages based on your need.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/BrQZR-lQYnl

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      "GroupByeditor": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$editor",
            "count": {
              "$sum": "1"
            },
            "lines": {
              "$sum": "$lines"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "GroupFilename": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "$filename",
            "count": {
              "$sum": "1"
            },
            "lines": {
              "$sum": "$lines"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      
    }
  }
])
```

here I am having two group by in facet to get the stats based on editor and by filename.